# akka.streams.Source that you can emit values (similar to monix.BehaviorSubject)

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http, monix

I'm looking for `akka.stream.scaladsl.Source` construction method that will allow me to simply emit next value from different place of code (e.g. watching on system events).

- I need somethig similar to `Promise`. Promise emits single value to `Future`. I need to emit multiple values to `Source`.
- like `monix.reactive.subjects.BehaviorSubject.onNext(_)`
- I don't care about backpressure too much.

currently I've implemented this using monix & akka-streams (code below) but I expect that there should be akka-streams only sollution:

```scala
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Sink, Source}
import monix.reactive.subjects.BehaviorSubject
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global

val bs = BehaviorSubject("") //monix subject is sink and source at the same time

//this is how it is currently implemented
def createSource() = { 
    val s1 = Source.fromPublisher(bs.toReactivePublisher) //here we create source from subject
    Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupled[String, String](Sink.ignore, s1)
}

//somewhere else in code... some event happened
//this is how it works in monix.
val res:Future[Ack] = bs.onNext("Event #1471 just happened!") //here we emit value
```

Comment: Maybe this topic would be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397424/how-to-use-an-akka-streams-sourcequeue-with-playframework

Comment: Yes... this was helpful. The `Source.queue(...)` solves a problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [Actor Source](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/typed/stream.html#actor-sink)

An example from the docs:

```
import akka.actor.typed.ActorRef
import akka.stream.OverflowStrategy
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{ Sink, Source }
import akka.stream.typed.scaladsl.ActorSource

trait Protocol
case class Message(msg: String) extends Protocol
case object Complete extends Protocol
case class Fail(ex: Exception) extends Protocol

val source: Source[Protocol, ActorRef[Protocol]] = ActorSource.actorRef[Protocol](completionMatcher = {
  case Complete =>
}, failureMatcher = {
  case Fail(ex) => ex
}, bufferSize = 8, overflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.fail)

val ref = source
  .collect {
    case Message(msg) => msg
  }
  .to(Sink.foreach(println))
  .run()

ref ! Message("msg1")
```

This way you would be able to send messages to actor via actor system, and these messages will be emitted from the `ActorSource` down the stream.

Comment: looks promising. Still testing. It need additional dependency.

Comment: I've not used it (other problems), but it answers my question well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Source` abstraction, as name says, provide API to work with data source. Instead, you need to take a look at abstraction which consumes data - `Sink`. And `Sink.foreach` operation is what you are looking for, most likely: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Sink/foreach.html

In you case, the code would look something like:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}

val s1 = Source.// your WS akka stream source
s1.runWith(Sink.foreach(write))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not what i wanted. I really need to create Source... not Sink. I just need to create it in such way that items could be emitted from other parts of code freely. Something like Promise and Future.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `sink.foreach`.it invoke a given procedure for each element received.I think code will look like:

```
s1.runWith(Sink.foreach(write))
```

Essentially, what is being done is that for stream a source, sink tries to write every element of that stream.

**EDIT**

I think you are looking for `maybe`. It creates a source that emits once the materialized Promise is completed with a value.Check out this [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/maybe.html)

**EDIT**

[futureSource](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/futureSource.html) may also work.It streams the elements of the given future source once it successfully completes it.

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: Not what I need. I've improved question.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please let me know if it helps!!

Comment: Nice try... but still. It will emit only single value. I expect to emit them continuously... Whenever something interesting in system happens.

Comment: So, let's say that once the future completes, you want to stream that data. Am I right?

Comment: Future emits one item... I need something that could emit more than one.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Using `futureSource` might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/fromIterator.html or https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/fromPublisher.html is what you need, depending on where does your Source consume data from.